# About repayment of debt owed by a deceased

Tags: debt

My question is that can a person repay the debt of his deceased friend. There is a confusion since he is not his heir. If that can't be done what if this person right a will to his friends giving his that much money and repay his debt from that. I need to know one more should the will be written before the death or I can be willed after the death also. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not obligatory for friends or non-heirs to pay off the debt, but if they choose to do so voluntarily, it is considered a meritorious act.